# ts-jest not able to locate module

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

I'm building a web-app that depends upon vertigis-studio-web-SDK and React. To test that app I'm using testing-library/react as seen in my package.json:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "vertigis-web-sdk build",
        "start": "vertigis-web-sdk start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
        "@types/jest": "^28.1.0",
        "@vertigis/web": "5.17.0",
        "@vertigis/web-sdk": "1.5.0",
        "jest": "^28.1.0",
        "ts-jest": "^28.0.4",
        "typescript": "^4.3.2"
    },
    "dependencies": { ... }
}
```

In my react-component I have this piece of code:

```
import {
      LayoutElement,
      LayoutElementProperties,
} from "@vertigis/web/components";
import MenuItem from "@vertigis/web/ui/MenuItem";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@vertigis/web/ui/Select";
import Typography from "@vertigis/web/ui/Typography";
import { FC } from "react";

const OperatList: FC<LayoutElementProperties<OperatListModel>> = (
      props
) => {
      const { model } = props;
return <LayoutElement {...props} stretch> ...</LayoutElement>
```

which compiles fine using `npm run build`.

When I now run `npm run test` however I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

> 1 | import FeatureLayer from "@arcgis/core/layers/FeatureLayer";
    | ^
  2 | import { MapModel } from "@vertigis/web/mapping/MapModel";
  3 | import { command } from "@vertigis/web/messaging";
  4 | import { ComponentModelBase, ComponentModelProperties, importModel, serializable } from "@vertigis/web/models";

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1796:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Operat/OperatListModel.ts:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
```

This is my test-code within `src/__test__/MyTest.tsx`

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import OperatList, { OperatListModel } from './../components/Operat';

describe('Fixture', () => {
  test('First Test', () => {
    const model = new OperatListModel();
    render(<OperatList model={model} preloadChildren={function (): Promise<void> {
      return;
    }} />);

  }, 20000);
});
```

What drives me nuts is that I can render that component within my app without any problems. However running jest I'm not able to import the dependency.

I already checked this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv/issues/309) and implemented a `moduleNameMapper` as follows within my `jest.config.js`:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  "^@vertigis/web/components": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@vertigis/web/components/index"
},
```

but that gave me the following error:

> Could not locate module @vertigis/web/components mapped as:
> C:\Users\Carschtn\Documents\GitHub\AV_App\node_modules@vertigis\web\components\index

which is exactly the path where the module is located on my machine.

Comment: Is there an actual `import` statement in your `node_modules` which you are including? I think that either means there's something wrong in how that was included or that module is targetting a different module configuration than what you have in your tsconfig.json e.g. if you have `"module": "commonjs",` you might need `"module": "ES6",` or something like that

Comment: @apokryfos I'm not sure I got your question. In my `tsconfig` there's this entry: `"extends": "@vertigis/web-sdk/config/tsconfig.json"`, which directs to a `"module": "esnext"`. However in both files I have different `baseUrl`-elements. I'm not sure if and how those two interact.